# Stop console.log from library command?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript library I'm using that has a function. The function does some useful stuff and then prints to console.

Is there anyway to run the function without printing to console?

Comment: remove the line from the library?

Comment: There's no "good" solution, you can override console.log before the function and replace it after

Comment: As @epascarello said, I would find the line in the library that prints to console and comment it out.

Comment: Why would you care?? It doesn't slow anything enough to worry about performance and it provides information of where you are in the code. Yes you can remove it, but if you ever update the library you will most likely have to remove it again..

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the console.log function... Though that would likely work.

Comment: @CayceK "Why would you care" is not relevant to the question

Comment: then the answer is limitless. There is no reason for removing that functionality or editing it. I ask because why would it matter if it is there or it isn't. Most of your users will never see it. Unless it displays data you don't want to show. Then just delete it.

Comment: also.. is this really a "problem" for SO... yes you want it gone, but you're not providing a problem case. just saying.

Comment: @CayceK - maybe the OP needs to support older IE versions, in which console.log() will give an error and break the function. That's a reason to remove it.

Comment: Open that library in Notepad++, open `Find and replace` box, search `console.log` and replace it with `//console.log`

Comment: @nnnnnn acceptable but if that's the case it should be mentioned. Also these answers are super low quality. They can never really be anything but low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can find de `console.log()` statement and comment it.

If you are using a NPM package, you can fork the original repository, comment the console.log and then specify your repository url as the library source in your `package.json`:

`"library-name": "https://github.com/user/library.git"`